# Open Source Authentication Classifier

Tags: authentication, machine-learning, classification

I understand that authentication is essentially classifying hundreds or thousands of classes (individuals). Is there an open source classifier that can be used for the task?

Comment: I don't see the how authentication can be  classification problem. Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm not sure you're thinking of the right type of authentication. In authentication/verification, you create a template of a user (training), and then check that template against new instances to determine if it is an imposter user or genuine user.

Comment: So what type of authentication should I be thinking about? Are you talking about challenge-response authentication? If you want your questions to be easily answered you should be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the authentication. But I'll answer anyway.

Weka is popular and I have used it before, however I've never used it for such a large number of classes to be classified, but that doesn't mean it can't be done!

Weka: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

It has a GUI and a really easy-to-use Java library, if you're hard-coding.  I don't know what you're looking for as you haven't really said, but this is what I suggest!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I'm obviously we'll aware of Weka. This is a specific question.